# Tabs control in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I have three tabs and the data is divided in all the three tabs. Each data record has a set of action such as edit and delete. The first tab is being loaded with the page and on click of each tab there is an Ajax call to fetch the data for the tab. I want to maintain the active state of the current tab. e.g. if I edit a record from the second tab, user is taken to the edit page. When the record is edited successfully, I want the second tab active. I tried to send the tab id using "get" and saved it in session variable. On the page I added a hidden field and set the value. In jquery, I checked the value of the hidden field and called function like this :

```
var tab_id = $("#tab_history").val();
$("#"+tab_id).click();
```

But this is not working and the first tab is active by default. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: are you doing refereshing the page after edit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are getting the variable from the session, you can do something like:

```
$tabs = $("#MyTabs").tabs();

var tab_id = $("#tab_history").val();
$tabs.tabs('select', tab_id);
```

Where $tabs is your tabs that you defined as shown above.